# Ansible docker_container module - How to pass variables in environment section?

Tags: environment-variables, docker, ansible

In the below task:

```
- name: Create a data container
  docker_container:
    name: mydeploycontainer
    image: 1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
    env:
      name1: {{name1_var}}
      name2: {{name2_var}}
      name3: {{name3_var}}
```

---

`env:` section only allows value with double quotes, something like:

```
    env:
      name1: "value1"
```

---

But these are dynamic values based on the inputs passed to playbook:

`--extra-vars '{ "name1_var": "value_1", "name2_var": "value_2", "name3_var": "value_3" }'`

---

How to pass variable to environment section?

Comment: What error do you get with ansible?

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR;

All jinja2 template expressions **must be quoted** in your playbook when they **start with double curly braces** else you will get a syntax error (Which is what you get I guess)

You should write your task like the following to clear your error and set your envs to your passed extra vars:

```yaml
- name: Create a data container
  docker_container:
    name: mydeploycontainer
    image: 1111112222.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteam/app-deploy:v.1
    env:
      name1: "{{ name1_var }}"
      name2: "{{ name2_var }}"
      name3: "{{ name3_var }}"
```

As a good practice, you should always quote your strings when they contain jinja2 templating expressions even when they don't start with double curly braces (e.g. `path: "/fix/path/{{ var_file_name }}"`)

For further information see [Ansible yaml syntax gotchas](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

## POC

Here is a proof of concept I wrote and played with ansible 2.8.1 to show you it works as expected. To replay, make sure you `pip install jmespath` as I used `json_query` for debugging values.

The `test.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Test passing vars to docker from command line
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Spin up a container
      docker_container:
        state: started
        image: busybox:latest
        command: sh -c "while true; do sleep 1000; done"
        name: test_for_so
        env:
          oneenv: "{{ oneenv_value }}"
          otherenv: "{{ otherenv_value }}"

    - name: Get env values from container
      command: >-
        docker exec test_for_so sh -c 'echo ${{ item }}'
      register: env_out
      loop:
        - oneenv
        - otherenv

    - name: Display collected values
      debug:
        msg: "{{ env_out.results | json_query('[].{env: item, value: stdout}') }}"
```

The command:

```bash
ansible-playbook test.yml \
  -e '{"oneenv_value": "This is value 1", "otherenv_value": "This is value 2"}'
```

And the result:

```
PLAY [Test passing vars to docker from command line] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Spin up a container] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Get env values from container] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=oneenv)
changed: [localhost] => (item=otherenv)

TASK [Display collected values] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "env": "oneenv",
            "value": "This is value 1"
        },
        {
            "env": "otherenv",
            "value": "This is value 2"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

## Counter POC

If you remove the quotes around the jinja2 templates strings in the env section (as in your example), this is what happens:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')

The error appears to be in '/home/user/test.yml': line 15, column 20, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        env:
          oneenv: {{ oneenv_value }}
                   ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: Your example doesn't prove what you say (you say it won't work unless it's quoted, but there's no unquoted instance in your example to show that it doesn't work unless quoted). And in Ansible docs, you can find instances of unquoted usage. Example: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#tasks-list

Comment: Yes, that's better. It'll be even better if you mention which version of ansible you tested with.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want (`ansible 2.8`)

```
-e 'name1_var=""testa"" name2_var=""testb"" name1_var3=""testc""'
```

Comment: What about `name1: "{{name1_var}}"`?

Comment: @user103944 I made the same mistake as you when overlooking the question... passing variables is not the issue here and works correctly with json. The problem is the wrong syntax for templating those vars in the playbook. See my answer.